# read_pptx() throwing error when trying to read a pptx template file

Tags: r, officer

I am trying to generate a report using a template .pptx file provided to me (originally within a zipped folder, which I extracted and saved locally). 
R is giving me the following error when I run this code:

```
doc <- read_pptx('template_files/empty_template/RL_Template.pptx')
```

Error in tmp_names[match(old_, tmp_names)] <- new_ : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

The file RL_Template.pptx is a powerpoint template that will be populated with text and images. All scripts, data files, and templates are contained inside an R project, again, saved locally.

I have tried to execute the same line of code on a different machine of mine and get the same error, although a collaborator can successfully download/unzip the same files, run the same code, and generate the appropriate powerpoint output. He and I are running the same versions of R and RStudio.
I can successfully run this line of code to create a new object in R:

```
foo<-read_pptx()
```

and can add content to foo using add_slide()

I have updated all associated packages. I have full admin privileges on my machine so it should not be an error with read/write permissions.
It seems like maybe a problem with zip? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Session info:

R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.8.4          readxl_1.3.1         flextable_0.5.7      officer_0.3.6        SWMPrExtension_1.1.2 SWMPr_2.3.1
[7] zoo_1.8-7            ggplot2_3.2.1

Comment: it looks like a bug, could you post a reproducible example and attach RL_Template.pptx? (on github if you can't here)

Comment: @DavidGohel I am moving this to github